# Linking Angular form and getting form values via email

Tags: angular, forms, email

I'm new to Angular and never hosted a website. I have a contact form and obviously need the inputs to my email when the form gets submitted. How can I go about this

Comment: You will need some sort of server to send your Angular form values to, and the server will need to send an email. There are many ways to go about this, but without being specific on how/where you will host your app and what server technology you will be using, you won't really get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pragmatic / simple solution

Probably not what you expected, but the simplest solution is a mailto link. What it will do is it will start the user's email with a new email, and the `to` field filled in with the address you want. You might be even able to prefill the subject and body, see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/ or search for *mailto link*.

#### Complete solution

The angular app runs in the browser. The browser can't send mails. You need to have a backend, and a REST endpoint in it, where your angular app can post the contents of the contact form. The backend then can send an email with the contents of the contact form via any kind of email service, or your backend might have an email service (most probably it doesn't).